# How to Differentiate SaveAs call and Save call in PowerPoint events?

Tags: vb.net, vsto, powerpoint, add-in

I'm writting AddIn for PowerPoint 2010. I'm using two functions of PowerPoint.

```
Application_PresentationBeforeSave(ByVal Pres As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

Application_PresentationSave(ByVal Pres As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation)
```

When I perform Save operation (Ctrl+S) or SaveAs (File -> SaveAs) on powerpoint it executes `Application_PresentationBeforeSave()` method.

But I need to differentiate these two calls (Ctril+S & SaveAs) and accordingly perform some task. So how can I differentiate these two calls in BeforeSave method ??

As for Word, in `Application_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByRef SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)` there is SaveAsUI flag which differentiate whether this method has been called by SaveAs or Ctrl+S action.

So is there any flag/property which differtiate same things in PowerPoint ??

Comment: Ctrl+S is just a keyword shortcut isn't your question about trying to differentiate between `File>Save` and `File>SaveAs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Eugene for showing me a way.
My problem got resolve. I tried your suggestion.

Here is the description of my solution.
I have added function call in Ribbon.xml

In MySaveAs() function I set one glbal variable. And used it in BeforeSave mthod.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. Would you mind sharing your Ribbon.xml? I can't seem to find the right idMso to repurpose SaveAs in PowerPoint 2010. I can repurpose Save, but not SaveAs

Comment: Sorry but I left that project so dont have an access of that Ribbon.xml. You tell me which idMso do you require ? I can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to repurpose the ribbon buttons or replace the backstage UI controls with your own so you will know what action users chose in the UI. In case of ribbon controls see the [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN. The Backstage UI is described in the following articles in MSDN in depth:

[Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833(v=office.14).aspx)

[Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851(v=office.14).aspx)

In case of Ctrl+S shortcuts you need set a keyboard hook using Windows API functions, see [Using shortcut keys to call a function in an Office Add-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/09/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in.aspx) for more information.